# Some questions from a newbie on Docker and Docker Elasticsearch image

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, dockerfile

I'm new on both Elasticsearch and Docker and I have some questions about them. I retrieved docker/elastic image via the following command:

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.2
```

And I started it in this way:

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "transport.host=127.0.0.1" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.2
```

Here are my questions:

1. I know from docker documentation that "docker run" commands is used to run a specific command inside a container. So according to the previous one, what's the unix command?

   docker run -p 9200:9200 (Publish all exposed ports to random ports) -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "transport.host=127.0.0.1" (Set environment variables) docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.2 (image name)

So where is the command? I suspect it's like elasticsearch starts together with the container. If so, how image's creator did that?

2. What's the best way of running the container without elastic's stdout?
3. I tried to build a custom docker image based on CentOS in which I would like to install elasticsearch like a service (via rpm). Installation works fine but when I try to run elasticsearch.service via systemctl I get the following error:

> Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer the questions one by one:

1. This is done by providing a default `CMD` in the Dockerfile linked [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/blob/5.4/templates/Dockerfile.j2). Also, `docker run` is used to run a container where `CMD` can be provided with the command or the default is used as specified in `Dockerfile`. I would recommend reading about `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` in [detail](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).
2. You will have to use `-d` flag with it. It will run the container in detached mode giving you exactly what you are looking. Details [here.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d) May be add `--restart=always` to run it as a long running service.
3. Try with `sudo` ? there isn't enough information here to answer this part. Please provide logs for `systemd` service that might help.

I hope it helps!